# Изменение разрешения экрана

Tags: html, css

При изменении разрешения экрана неправильно отображается меню.

li, которые не помещаются на страницу - переносятся вниз и теряются стили. Помогите, пожалуйста, как сохранить стили?

```css
 *{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    ul.menu {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      display: block;
      background-color: #2b2b2b;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#4f4f4f), to(#2b2b2b));
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#4f4f4f, #2b2b2b);
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f4f4f, #2b2b2b);
      background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#4f4f4f, #2b2b2b);
      background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#4f4f4f, #2b2b2b);
      background-image: linear-gradient(#4f4f4f, #2b2b2b);
      min-width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
    }
    
    ul.menu li {
      float: left;
      list-style: none;
      border-right: 1px solid #4f4f4f;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    ul.menu li a {
      color: white;
      display: block;
      font-family: Arial;
      font-size: 13px;
      padding: 15px 40px;
      text-decoration: none;
      border-right: 1px solid #2b2b2b;
    }
    
    ul.menu li a:hover {
      background-color: #2b2b2b;
    }
    
    ul.menu li ul {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
    <ul class="menu">
       <li><a href="">Главная</a></li>
       <li><a href="">О компании</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Услуги</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Фотогалерея</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Цены</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Отзывы</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Контакты</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что Вы задали фон для элемента `.menu` и задали ему фиксированное значение высоты. Соответственно, при переносе дочерних элементов на новую строку, высота родителя остаётся прежней.

Вы не очень конкретно описали, какое поведение Вам нужно, но если для элемента с классом `.menu` убрать фиксированную высоту `height: 50px;` и добавить `overflow: auto;`, при переносе дочерних пунктов на новую строку, родитель растягивается до нужной высоты.

Результат:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    background-color: #2b2b2b;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#4f4f4f), to(#2b2b2b));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#4f4f4f, #2b2b2b);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f4f4f, #2b2b2b);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#4f4f4f, #2b2b2b);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#4f4f4f, #2b2b2b);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#4f4f4f, #2b2b2b);
    min-width: 100%;
    /* height: 50px; */
    overflow: auto;
}

ul.menu li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #4f4f4f;
    position: relative;
}

ul.menu li a {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 15px 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #2b2b2b;
}

ul.menu li a:hover {
    background-color: #2b2b2b;
}

ul.menu li ul {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="">Главная</a></li>
        <li><a href="">О компании</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Услуги</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Фотогалерея</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Цены</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Отзывы</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Контакты</a></li>
     </ul>
```

Также, современный подход - использование Flexbox.

Результат:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #2b2b2b;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#4f4f4f), to(#2b2b2b));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#4f4f4f, #2b2b2b);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f4f4f, #2b2b2b);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#4f4f4f, #2b2b2b);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#4f4f4f, #2b2b2b);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#4f4f4f, #2b2b2b);
    min-width: 100%;
    /* height: 50px; */
    /* overflow: auto; */

    display: flex;
}

ul.menu li {
    /* float: left; */
    flex-shrink: 0;
    list-style: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #4f4f4f;
    position: relative;
}

ul.menu li a {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 15px 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #2b2b2b;
}

ul.menu li a:hover {
    background-color: #2b2b2b;
}

ul.menu li ul {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="">Главная</a></li>
        <li><a href="">О компании</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Услуги</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Фотогалерея</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Цены</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Отзывы</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Контакты</a></li>
     </ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное overflow: auto; то, что нужно!